# Laravel function call and return in the same controller

Tags: php

I am new to laravel. I am having a doubt how to call other function inside the same controller and return the processed values to the function by which it has been invoked.  I have tried this similar to C language but the code doesn't works

```
class AgreementsApiController extends Controller
    {

      public function store($th_id,$mv_id,$wk1_terms,$wk2_terms,$wk3_terms)

        {
        //make a function call here to add function similar to
        $result=add($th_id,$mv_id);
        }

    public function add($th_id,$mv_id)

        { //process the parameters and return to store function

          $r=$th_id+$mv_id;
          return $r;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem isn't Laravel-related. Just Google "php call class method" and you should get an answer. It's a pretty basic thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your store function

```
 $result=$this->add($th_id,$mv_id);
```

and thats it.